# Push into array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
test = [{
         property1: "value 1",
         property2: "value 2"
       }];
```

if I do this

```
test.push[{property3: "value 3"}];
```

I get a new object. I want to add it to existing object.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
test[0].property3 = "value 3";
```

or

```
test[0]['property3'] = "value 3";
```